# When ios app manually kicked out, how to immediately release all resources

Tags: android, ios, .a

When the ios app manually forced exit immediately release all resourcesAPP manually after the killing, restart the APP will be caton, found that because of adding the size of the 3G .a library cause, processing way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzh8S.png)

Is there a better way?

Comment: As far as I know all the resources held by the app will be released once user force close the app and you need not do anything about it specifically. What kind of resources are u talking about ?

Comment: Did not immediately release, after being forced to shut down the program resources, program did not exit immediately, need 3 to 5 s